# Image not displaying in MVC project on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap on an MVC 5 project.

In the bootstrap CSS file, I have an image as a background on the banner. It is not displaying on the server (displays fine on my dev machine).

```
.navbar-brand {
float: left;
padding: 15px 15px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 20px;
background: url('../Content/Images/logo_combined_trans.gif') no-repeat left;display:block;
}
```

Additional observations:
1) The image displays perfectly on my development machine. Once I publish the files on the server, however, everything else works, except the image does not display.
2) I put the same image in the body of a View in an img tag and it displayed correctly too.
3) Interestingly when I inspected the element it looked like the background property of the CSS is not being read at all, the rest of the properties (float, padding....line-height show correctly).

I tried the following:
1) I gave the DefaultAppPool 'read' access to the Content and Images directories. Still no go.

Is there anything else that needs to be set on the server?

Thanks.

Comment: remove ..(2 dots in an url)  
mvc requests static content from content folder by default.

Comment: thanks but still no luck! 

i tried: 
1) background: url('/Content/Images/logo_combined_trans.gif') no-repeat left;display:block;
2) background: url('~/Content/Images/logo_combined_trans.gif') no-repeat left;display:block;
3) background: url('Content/Images/logo_combined_trans.gif') no-repeat left;display:block;

Comment: and tried:
4) background: url('http://myurl.com/Content/Images/logo_combined_trans.gif') no-repeat left;display:block;

Comment: Do I need to edit the bootstrap.min.css file? I edited the min file and it worked. I guess should I not put up the min file at all if bootstrap.css is going to be edited?

Comment: thanks for your help anyway Eugene.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I know what the problem was. I had a bootstrap.min.css which did not have the modifications that I had made to the orignal bootstrap.css. After I removed the min file from the server everything worked.

Also, I tried several versions of the URL and all of the above worked including the original version:
1) background: url('../Content/Images/logo_combined_trans.gif') no-repeat left;display:block;
2) background: url('~/Content/Images/logo_combined_trans.gif') no-repeat left;display:block;
3) background: url('Content/Images/logo_combined_trans.gif') no-repeat left;display:block;